# How to format and serve an apple-app-site-association file correctly

Tags: ios, app-store, ios-universal-links

I'm trying to set up an `apple-app-site-association` file for several apps that share a common set of paths. There are two sets of documentation from Apple that conflict. Firstly, [this doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016308-CH12-SW1) says that each app should have its own section and then there is a paths element that contains mappings:

```json
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appID": "9JA89QQLNQ.com.apple.wwdc",
                "paths": [ "/wwdc/news/", "/videos/wwdc/2015/*"]
            },
            {
                "appID": "ABCD1234.com.apple.wwdc",
                "paths": [ "*" ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Then there is [this doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/supporting-associated-domains) for XCode which shows a quite different format:

```json
{
  "applinks": {
      "details": [
           {
             "appIDs": [ "ABCDE12345.com.example.app", "ABCDE12345.com.example.app2" ],
             "components": [
               {
                  "#": "no_universal_links",
                  "exclude": true,
                  "comment": "Matches any URL whose fragment equals no_universal_links and instructs the system not to open it as a universal link"
               },
               {
                  "/": "/buy/*",
                  "comment": "Matches any URL whose path starts with /buy/"
               },
               {
                  "/": "/help/website/*",
                  "exclude": true,
                  "comment": "Matches any URL whose path starts with /help/website/ and instructs the system not to open it as a universal link"
               },
               {
                  "/": "/help/*",
                  "?": { "articleNumber": "????" },
                  "comment": "Matches any URL whose path starts with /help/ and which has a query item with name 'articleNumber' and a value of exactly 4 characters"
               }
             ]
           }
       ]
   },
   "webcredentials": {
      "apps": [ "ABCDE12345.com.example.app" ]
   },

    "appclips": {
        "apps": ["ABCED12345.com.example.MyApp.Clip"]
    }
}
```

Neither document has any date or version information, so I can't tell which is more recent or correct.

The appIDs themselves are also confusing because there are apparently multiple sources of these identifiers, but [not all of them will work](https://lickability.com/blog/insidious-bugs-number-3-apple-app-site-association-file/), though I can't tell if that's my problem now.

I'm serving my document from `/.well-known/apple-app-site-association`, but I find [a validator](https://limitless-sierra-4673.herokuapp.com) gives odd validation failures such as not being able to get the file (though fetching it with curl or a browser works fine), and a complaint that it can't be verified with openssl, which makes no sense because it contains nothing that's even vaguely related to certificates or signatures. Why does the document need to be delivered with a `application/pkcs7-mime` MIME type when it's neither MIME nor PKCS7 format?

Looking at [Apple's own AASA](https://www.apple.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association), I see that it uses **both** of these formats! It also fails validation in all of the validators I tried, including Apple's own! This is very confusing.

How exactly should this document be formatted?

Answer (score 2):

Like you mentioned, there seems to be two different types of `apple-app-site-association`, especially under the `applinks` key: `"appID"` and `"paths"` vs. `"appIDs"` and `"components"`. I'm guessing one of these might be the legacy API supported by Apple for backward compatibility.

I found documents for the `components` one:

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/applinks
- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/applinks/details
- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/applinks/details/components

Quoting what's available for the `components`:

> `/`: The pattern to match with the URL path component. The default is *, which matches everything.

> `?`: The pattern or dictionary to match with the URL query component. The default is *, which matches everything.

> `#`: The pattern to match with the URL fragment component. The default is *, which matches everything.

> `exclude`: A Boolean value that indicates whether to stop pattern matching and prevent the universal link from opening if the URL matches the associated pattern. The default is false.

> `comment`: Text that the system ignores. Use this to provide information about the URLs a pattern matches.

> `caseSensitive`: A Boolean value that indicates whether pattern matching is case-sensitive. The default is true.

> `percentEncoded`: A Boolean value that indicates whether URLs are percent-encoded. The default is true.